# ReactJS and Firebase: My Firebase-hosted website is not able to load resource from static/css directory

Tags: reactjs, firebase

My React project runs on my local without any problem, but does not on Firebase host.

I initialized the Firebase to use the "build" directory of my project. Here below is my firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.html inside the "build" directory demands:

```
<link href="/static/css/2.a93a873a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/main.9076e0a4.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/static/js/2.ff69b6bf.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.d20051fc.chunk.js"></script>
```

This is the console error log:

[image]

First of all, there is no file named "2.a93a873a.chunk.css" inside my static/css. However, it works on my local. The rest of the errors similar to this. Can you help me to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you building the app? Create react app?

Comment: And are there hidden files in the build folder or why is this in the ignore `"**/.*",`?

Comment: I am building the app with "npm run build"
No, there is no hidden file inside the build folder. I don't know why there is "**/.*" inside the json, it was automatically generated. I didn't type this.

Comment: How did you publish the app? `firebase deploy`?

Comment: Yes, "firebase deploy"

Comment: Can you try an empty ignore field? All files in the build folder should be published, Just remove the ignore

Comment: Nope, unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: That is weird. Also the ignore was fine, I think something else is wrong here. Every step you described is theoretically correct.

Comment: You can try and test your firebase hosting locally, check this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy

Comment: I agree, I don't understand why this does not work. Weird... Also, some of the files in the error log do not exist in the static/css. How can it demand a file that does not exist?

Comment: After running the build everything inside the build folder is auto generated. So assuming everything's correct you can't require a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see on the error log, some of those files do not exist in my build folder.

Comment: What happens when you run `npx serve build` - should host the build folder locally, same errors? Did you try remove the build folder and run a clean build? Even though this should automatically happen

Comment: "npx serve build" brought the same errors again. If I remove my build folder, how can it run the project? By the way, as I said above, it requires a file that doesn't exist: "2.a93a873a.chunk.css" (This is in the error log, but not in static/css actually)

Comment: Problem gone! I just rebuilt the project from scratch, and this worked. Thank you for your help @JulianKleine !